# Как переписать alertDialog?

Tags: android, recyclerview, alert

Использую один alertDialog в двух местах, но из-за этого появляется ошибка. Как можно переписать код?

```
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    final View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.create, null);

    subject = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_subject);
    text = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_text);

    builder.setView(view);

    /*
    * Редактирование записи
    * */
    recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getApplicationContext(),
            recyclerView, new RecyclerTouchListener.ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position) {
            builder.setTitle(note_update);
            builder.setPositiveButton(add, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            });

            builder.setNegativeButton(cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            });

            builder.show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

        }
    }));

    /*
    * Создание и сохранение новой записи
    * */
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            builder.setTitle(note_new);
            builder.setPositiveButton(add, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    writable();
                    prepareData();
                }
            });

            builder.setNegativeButton(cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            builder.show();
        }
    });
```

Ошибка такого плана

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Передавайте в `setView` сам ресурс разметки `R.layout.create` а затем ищите вьюхи вызывая `findViewById` непосредственно у `AlertDialog`

А кстати так диалог создавать никогда не пробовал. Если не получится, то перепишите код так, чтобы он создавался в двух местах с нуля